# Ionic 2 getting device info

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am having some real issues trying to get device details using Ionic 2.

Whenever I try: Device.uuid I get "Device is not defined", my code is as follows:

user-service.ts:

```
import { Device } from 'ionic-native';
    linkDevice(pin, onComplete) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            var linkDeviceData = {
                grant_type: 'pin',
                platform: Device.platform,
                uuid: Device.uuid,
                pin: pin
            };
    this.http.post("myUrl","&uuid=" + Device.uuid)...
```

app.modules.ts:

```
import { Device } from 'ionic-native';
...
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }, Device, UserService]
```

calling.ts:

```
this.userService.linkDevice(this.pin,
```

I am not sure if I need to have another constructor in my calling class or if I am just missing something stupid.

I am at my wits end with this, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `Device.uuid` does return the correct id, but only while not debugging, when used in an alert or once received on API end, the correct values are shown.

So this only works when NOT debugging

Answer (score 0):

to get a device info check this one

```
import { Device } from 'ionic-native';
    linkDevice(pin, onComplete) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            var linkDeviceData = {
                grant_type: 'pin',
                platform: Device.device.platform,
                uuid: Device.device.uuid,
                pin: pin
            };
    this.http.post("myUrl","&uuid=" + Device.device.uuid)...
```

Comment: Device gives the following when debugging: Device is not defined

Comment: did you install the device plugin to your project @AltusBaard

Comment: ionic plugin list: cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console",
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device",
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen",
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar",
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist",
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

Comment: oh k device plugin works only in device it will through error in browser check in device

Comment: I am debugging on device

Comment: I tried showing it in an alert now while not debugging, then I do get the device details

Comment: comment all the code and import the device and then do `console.log(Device.device.uuid)`

Comment: When not debugging it works. Device.uuid return correct data then